# C++ object of class in class not given public access

Tags: c++

I have this setup and how i want to use it in main for example:

```
struct Player{

private:
    float posX1, posX2, posY1, posY2;
    int user_id;

public:
    Player::Player():posX1(NULL), posY1(NULL), posX2(NULL), posY2(NULL){};
    float getPosX1();
    float getPosY1();
    float getPosX2();
    float getPosY2();
    int getUserId();
    void setUserId(int);
    void setPosX1(float);
    void setPosY1(float);
    void setPosX2(float);
    void setPosY2(float);
};

struct Room_Data{

private:
    int room_id;
    Player player_one, player_two;
    bool playerOneAlive, playerTwoAlive;

public:
    Room_Data::Room_Data():player_one(), player_two(), playerOneAlive(false), playerTwoAlive(false), room_id(NULL){};
    void setRoomId(int);
    int getRoomId();
    void setPlayerOneDead();
    void setPlayerOneAlive();
    void setPlayerTwoDead();
    void setPlayerTwoAlive();
    bool isPlayerOneAlive();
    bool isPlayerTwoAlive();
    Player getPlayerOne();
    Player getPlayerTwo();
};
```

I'm trying to use the following method in main for example:

```
main.cpp

const int x=10;
Room_Data data[x];
data[0].getPlayerOne().setPosX1(10.0f);
```

But it doesnt set posx1 because getPlayerOne() provides only private access of the player_one object but i dont know how to give it public access

Comment: It might just be the case i am lacking sleep, but if i am not mistaken both methods are public. GetPlayerOne and SetPosX1 are public, so you should be able to access them even though the members are not public (that is just hiding the implementation from the outside, which is a good thing.

Comment: @user3125562: He's mixing terminology a bit, but he meant that -- through whatever mechanism -- he wasn't able to affect the internal member variable from external scope.

Comment: ^ if only i could verbalize my programming problems so clearly like you

Comment: @shawna: Give it time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By having `getPlayerOne` return a *reference* to that private variable.**

```
Player& getPlayerOne();
```

Then you will be able to perform stuff on the result of calling that function, and that *stuff* will apply to the actual, original member within your class.

Right now you're operating on a temporary copy, instead, due to returning by *value*.

---

Frankly, though, if you're going to allow unabashed access to this private variable, why bother with the getter? Just make the variable public.

Comment: Does that mean i HAVE to use pointers? ie: Player* player_one = new Player(); Then return the Player object like so: return &player_one;?

Comment: @shawna: No. In fact, at no time did I suggest using pointers. I said to return a _reference_. `Player& getPlayerOne() { return player_one; }`

Comment: I knew i was missing something, but its too late here ^^. Indeed returning by reference should give you the right object. As i said before both methods are public, that should not be the issue.